# What is used for parse_str() as json_last_error() is used for json_decode()?

Tags: php, json, mime-types, content-type, urlencode

The typical way to verify whether a string is JSON is as follows.  Is there a similar solution for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content?

```
$data=json_decode($string);
if(json_last_error()) //Not valid JSON
```

Comment: I think you should use `parse_str` instead of `urldecode`. I think the `urldecode` just swaps url encoded values to their literal characters so I don't think you'd get an error like you will while parsing malformed JSON. e.g. `str_replace('%20', ' ', $url)` is my guess, so either it would replace, or it wouldn't and if not it's not an error, just no match.

Comment: @user3783243  Yes, thanks I think I agree.   But how can one know whether `parse_str()` couldn't parse the string in question?  PS.  I will change the subject of my post.  Thanks

Comment: The array will be empty or there will be some PHP error thrown. I don't know of a function to return errors with that function.. Any errors I can think of would be PHP syntax errors and would be logged .